# Kerberos on Hadoop

Tags: security, hadoop, kerberos

I have an Apache Hadoop (1.0.4) cluster running. I'm now trying to implement security on cluster by adding Kerberos to it. I have a Kerberos KDC running independently. Is there any sort of documentation I can use to link the two?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [CDH4 Security guide](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Security-Guide/cdh4sg_topic_3.html) for detailed steps.